# Let span fill remaining width?

Tags: css

I have the following li item:

```
<li>
  <span style='float:left; background-color:red'>a</span>
  <span style='float:left; background-color:green'>b</span>
</li>
```

I'd like the span on the right to fill whatever width is remaining in its parent li. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't want to float each of them left, only the first one, and then make the second one display in block mode:

```html
<li>
  <span style="float:left; background-color:red">a</span>
  <span style="display: block; background-color:green">b</span>
</li>
```

Comment: This is not correct (neither is the other answer): Span does not fill the rest of the width, it fills the entire width - two spans overlap.

Comment: You can prevent the spans from overlapping by setting `overflow: hidden;` on the second one.

Answer (score 11):

Looked for the same solution, but found only this which worked great for me:

```html
<li>
  <span style='display: table-cell; background-color:red'>a</span>
  <span style='display: table-cell; width: 100%; background-color:green'>b</span>
</li>
```

All you need is just using table-cell displaying **and** set filler span width to 100%. All other solutions I've tried didn't work for me as expected.

Comment: You made typo in 2nd span: "dispaly". Also quotes are traditionally double when setting style, so it should be: style="..."

Comment: @LechOsiński Thanks, fixed. What about "double-quoted traditions" - not sure that traditions make any sense in IT/science. W3.org makes no preference for any kind of quotes btw.

Comment: problem with this is that it breaks a sentence tho' it would possibly fit in one line.

Answer (score 6):

Don't float the second one, and make it `display:block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ymAt5/

Comment: As with Michael Shimmins' response, this makes the second item the same width as the container - it doesn't fill the _remaining_ space

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid layout:

```
<li class="my-grid">
  <span class="left">a</span>
  <span class="right">b</span>
</li>
```

And the css :

```
.my-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
}

.left{
  background: red;
}

.right{
  background: blue;
}
```

Play with the **grid-template-columns** property so it suits your needs.

https://jsfiddle.net/c9j3ok7u/