# How to use CSS to make a line before and after span with text inside div

Tags: css

I have a span with text inside a div. In front of that span I want a 2 px line to go to the edge on the left. After the text I want a simular line to go to the right edge of the parent element.

**Current markup:**

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <span class="label" style="padding-left: 40px;">This is my text</span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Expected result:**

```
----- This is my text --------------------------
```

**What is the best solution for my problem?**

I have tried to use a extra span for the line after the text. Did not manage to get it right. It is based on [Let span fill remaining width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499314/let-span-fill-remaining-width). My attempt can be found at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yDLuK/1/)

**Update:**

The parent div has a gradient color as background and a height. Background-color on the text can't be used AFAIK.

```
<div style="
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #99D166;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #C0E3A1), color-stop(3%, #A6D77A), color-stop(100%, #8CCB52));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C0E3A1, #A6D77A 3%, #8CCB52);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #C0E3A1, #A6D77A 3%, #8CCB52);
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;">
```

Comment: Play with this & u will get the answer http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/yDLuK/7/

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<span class="label">You're Text Message</span>
```

CSS

```
span.label:after{content:"------------";padding-right:15px;letter-spacing:-1px;color:#3399ff;}
span.label:before{content:"------------";padding-left:15px;letter-spacing:-1px;color:#3399ff;}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/2qLptucL/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

**CSS**

```
.label {
    margin-left: 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    background:#fff;
}

.parent {
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
    width: 400px;
    height:9px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yDLuK/3/

Comment: For exact style add border-style: dashed; to .parent.

Comment: Dashed borders is not a point here. It was just to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired results through positiong as well as :-

**CSS**

```
.label {
    background: white;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
}

.line {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <span class="label">This is my text</span>
    <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yDLuK/6/

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle comes close to doing this, you just need to position the one element on top of the other (if you want to do this in pure CSS). Another alternative is to split the line element into two - one for before, and one for after the text.

While you could use negative margins to move it up on top of the line, it might make sense to enclose the text and line element in a container element, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/2FuDK/), and use relative positioning on the container and absolute positioning on the text and line within the container element.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="label">This is my text</span>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
}

.label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0.5em;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WVzNf/

I reworked Shailender Arora's idea, to use border dashed instead.

Another method might be to remove the border and use a background image instead. That way you can have full control over its appearance.