# Getting an input to fill remaining width like a span element

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to have a text input fill the horizontal space remaining in a div.

The answer here provides a simple example of doing this with a span: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3499333/165673, but for some reason I can't get my input element to behave in the same way.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<span class="a">something</span>
<span class="b">fill the rest</span> 
</div>

<div>
<span class="a">something</span>
<input class="b" value="fill the rest">       
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.a {
    float:left; background-color:red
}
.b {
    background-color:green;display:block;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FKZUA/1/

In the first example, span.b fills the remaining space. However, input.b won't.

Comment: Hey you can add width to input button as input is different than span with the property so that why it not fill the rest so CSS for input is `input{min-width:80% or some px value}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

### css

```css
.a {
    display:table-cell; background-color:red;
}
.b {
    display:table-cell; background-color:green; width:100%;
}
.c { width:100%; }
​
```

### html

```html
<div>
  <span class="a">something</span>
  <span class="b">fill the rest</span> 
</div>
<div>
  <span class="a">something</span>
  <span class="b"><input class="c" value="fill the rest" /></span>
</div>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FKZUA/55/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ol' table display trick here. Lose the float and set the `div` to *display: table;* and the children to *display: table-cell;*.

[Here's an example showing it.](http://jsfiddle.net/zcn2p/) You may need some adjusting to the get the *'something'* the way you want it (for instance, setting a width), but that might be more than what you want to do.

```
div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.a, .b {
  display: table-cell;
}
.b {
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks jmeas- you got me most of the way there but Mark brought it home

Comment: Yeah he definitely nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
button.send {
    float: right;

    
}
span.send {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
 
}
input.send {
    width:100%;
    
}
```

html:

```
<button type="button" id = "send_button" class="send" >SEND</button><span class="send"><input type="text" id = "newmessage" class="send" required></span>
```